# Python text to tree structure creation

Tags: python, parsing

I have to perform text parsing using python, The sample text is as below

```
04h; ParIsa.Front.Area[0].ub_Y (BYTE)
0Dh; ParIsa.Front.Area[0].ub_X (BYTE)
00h; ParIsa.Front.Area[0].ub_P1 (BYTE)
01h; ParIsa.Front.Area[0].ub_P2 (BYTE)
40h; ParIsa.Front.Area[1].ub_Y (BYTE)
0Eh; ParIsa.Front.Area[1].ub_X (BYTE)
00h; ParIsa.Front.Area[1].ub_P1 (BYTE)
01h; ParIsa.Front.Area[1].ub_P2 (BYTE)
03h; ParIsa.Side.Area[0].ub_Y (BYTE)
0Dh; ParIsa.Side.Area[0].ub_X (BYTE)
00h; ParIsa.Side.Area[0].ub_P1 (BYTE)
01h; ParIsa.Side.Area[0].ub_P2 (BYTE)
41h; ParIsa.Side.Area[1].ub_Y (BYTE)
15h; ParIsa.Side.Area[1].ub_X (BYTE)
00h; ParIsa.Side.Area[1].ub_P1 (BYTE)
01h; ParIsa.Side.Area[1].ub_P2 (BYTE)
```

with such a text, I need to create a data structure in such a way that I can access the individual elements as well as the whole structure, for example

```
>> Side.Area[0].ub_X
'0x0d'

>> Front.Area
Area[0]
    ub_X = 0x0d
    ub_Y = 0x04
    ub_P1 = 0x00
    ub_P2 = 0x01
Area[1]
    ub_X = 0x0e
    ub_Y = 0x40
    ub_P1 = 0x00
    ub_P2 = 0x01
```

Accessing the structure as a whole is the difficult part, Can creation of tree be useful here? do you have any suggestions or ideas to implement this, please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the homogeneity of your input, a regular expression may be the preferred solution here.

```
import re
linere = re.compile(r"^(?P<value>[0-9a-fA-F]+)h; ParIsa\.(?P<name>[a-zA-Z.]+)\[(?P<index>\d+)\]\.(?P<attribute>[0-9a-zA-Z_]+) \(BYTE\)$")
```

Then you can apply the compiled regular expression to every line and access the portions of interest by name on the `.groupdict()` result of a match object.